# Why is the "Get" button missing from MacOS Big Sur download page?

Tags: mac-appstore, big-sur

Context: MacBook Air 2014, Sierra, to be upgraded to MacOS Big Sur.  The Get or Download button is missing.  Why?

[image]

A search for Big Sur in the AppStore fails to return the installer:

[image]

Comment: Try this instead https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Comment: What year MacBook Air? Your Mac needs to be a 2013 or newer model to install Big Sur.